# How to use data-src in React

Tags: reactjs, image, division, src

I need to use data-src attribute in < div > to show an image but in react this attribute for me is not working, is there any way to fix that?

```
<div
  data-aos="fade-up"
  data-aos-easing="ease-in-out"
  data-aos-duration="600"
  data-aos-once="true"
>
  <a href="#">
    <div data-src="../../contents/images/01.jpg">
      <div>
          //some text here
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

When I tested it in simple html it is working and no problem and image shows correctly, but in react it is not Ok...

Comment: "this attribute for me is not working" - in what way? You cant' set it or you can't read it? Please be more specific and show the code that isn't working.

Comment: data-src its jest to store some data, it has no value for image.. and will not add anything to the image itself, just the attribute with the stored data

Comment: @James Thank you, I added a code

Comment: @Roy.B So why when I set an address of an image for it, it shows?

Comment: @Waki `<div data-src="...">` isn't standard HTML for viewing an image, are you using a library?

Comment: @James No but I found my problem, I have set background-image for div in a css file and I forgot it, the image read from there.